# Disable Google Search page's arrows besides results when scrolling up/down using keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, javascript, google-search

[image: Google Search]

The blue arrow (marked in the figure above) hijacks the <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> in the keyboard and causes the page to jump on each result instead of scrolling smoothly. [This page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1027308) says that it has been bundled with Google Instant, and thus can be disabled ONLY by changing the search settings, which is inconvenient for private browsing.

**Question:** Besides disabling JavaScript, I'd like to hear any trick, add-on, etc. that makes the page to scroll normally like any page on the Web, when using the <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> keys, preferably in Chrome.

**Effected browsers:** Chrome & Firefox; Edge is not effected (probably will be later)

**Effected Websites:** Google Search (Web, Image, Video, books, etc.)

**OS:** Windows 10, 64-bit.

The arrow keys are quick to use when you are on a laptop. And I lose what line I was reading when the page is jumping on each result, contrary to the smooth scrolling.

EDIT: It seems Google itself backed and scrapped this 'feature'. Arrows are now back to normal scrolling.

Comment: I've confirmed this; but unlike @Sanny, I think I've seen it happen with both IE11 (Windows 7) and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Holding down CTRL while using <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> overrides that blue arrow and causes the scrolling to act normal (tested with latest FF and IE11 on Windows 10).

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. But the combination in Firefox only acted like `HOME` and `END` keys; i.e. go to page's top/bottom (probably you disabled Instant Search?)  Moreover, I should have mentioned that I wanted the solution for Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings and disable instant search. This fixes it.

Comment: well, i've said above that "[it] can be disabled ONLY when signing-in to Google which is **inconvenient**."

Comment: This is completely wrong. Go to google.com and click on Settings -> Search Settings. There you can disable it without signing-in.

Comment: I've got to say that you can disable instant without signing in. However, what if I'm on incognito or private browsing? I need an automated solution and signing in to Google looks more convenient than changing search settings every time I browse privately. Thank you anyway.